# Error when using options fields in Yesod subsite form

Tags: haskell, yesod, yesod-forms

I'm trying to use a `selectFieldList` inside a subsite form but I get the following error:

```
Couldn't match type 'IO' with 'HanderT master IO'
```

I'm running into this problem when using the following snippets, where the subsite is named `TestSub` (this subsite is separated from the master site):

Types:

```
type TestHandler a = forall master. Yesod master
    => HandlerT TestSub (HandlerT master IO) a

type Form a = forall master. Yesod master
    => Html -> MForm (HandlerT TestSub (HandlerT master IO)) (FormResult a, WidgetT TestSub IO ())
```

Form & handler:

```
testForm :: Form (Text, Int)
testForm = renderBootstrap3 BootstrapBasicForm $ (,)
    <$> areq textField (bfs MsgText) Nothing
    <*> areq (selectFieldList [(MsgFirst, 1), (MsgSecond, 2)]) (bfs MsgSelect) Nothing

getTestHome :: TestHandler Html
getTestHome = do
    (formWidget, _) <- generateFormPost testForm
    defaultLayoutSub $ do
        setTitleI MsgTest
        [whamlet|^{formWidget}|]
```

when the select field is replaced with for instance an `intField` the form and handler work as expected. While looking for the `selectFieldList` on Hoogle I found that options fields (select, radio, checkbox) have a different signature (displayed below) then the "normal" fields. I suspect this difference to be the problem but haven't found a work-around without having to implement the option fields all over.

Options field signature:

```
selectFieldList :: (Eq a, RenderMessage site FormMessage, RenderMessage site msg)
                => [(msg, a)]
                -> Field (HandlerT site IO) a
```

Normal field signature:

```
intField :: (Monad m, Integral i, RenderMessage (HandlerSite m) FormMessage)
         => Field m i
```

Is there a way to get the options fields to work in a subsite context, without reimplementing them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's usually best to run your forms in the master site, not the subsite, by calling `lift`. You'll also need to modify your type synonyms a bit to match, but the basic idea is to replace:

```
(formWidget, _) <- generateFormPost testForm
```

with

```
(formWidget, _) <- lift $ generateFormPost testForm
```

**EDIT**

I still recommend the above approach. However, to get the alternate that you're asking for, change your type synonym to:

```
type Form a =
   Html -> MForm (HandlerT HelloSub IO) (FormResult a, WidgetT HelloSub IO ())
```

and then use `liftHandlerT`:

```
liftHandlerT $ generateFormPost testForm
```

Keep in mind that this isn't how subsites are designed to be used, so you'll likely end up with some more friction as you keep going.

Regarding master translations: you can definitely leverage them, you just put in a constraint along the lines of `RenderMessage master MessageDataType`. That's what's used for `FormMessage` all over the place.

**EDIT2**

One more incantation you may find useful:

```
defaultLayoutSub $ liftWidgetT widget
```

Comment: I had it that way at first but that didn't allow me to use the subsite i18n messages. Which I would really like to use because the subsites is packages separately from the master site so I'm not able to use the master translations. Aside from the messages it would mean that I have to add additional code to render all the routes (`getRouteToParent`) which I would like to avoid. Is there another way to make the options fields work without having to run the form in the master site?

Comment: Well, it was designed to be used this way on purpose, so that each user of your subsite could override translations themselves. That said, I *think* using something like `hoist liftIO` should help here (hoist coming from mmorph). I can't test that myself now unfortunately.

Comment: I haven't gotten in to work with `hoist liftIO`, but that might be because im unsure about where to place those functions. Aside from getting the form to work in a subsite I do not see how I could use master site messages with a separately packaged subsite. This because the package won't compile when it doesn't know a message, and it could never know which messages master has because its packaged separately.

Comment: There's prior art on this in the yesod-auth package. Have a look theere.

Comment: MichaelSnoyman: Do you mean by "prior art in yesod-auth" the forms from the handlers in the `Email` module? Because non of those forms make use of `AForm` or 'MForm`. Thanks!

Comment: `runInputPost` follows the same pattern as the `AForm` and `MForm` stuff. I'll see about putting together a minimal example to help out here.

Comment: Eventually I ended up using the recommended approach because this has the benefit of making my translations overwritable by the master site, which seems useful in most situations. But the other options might be useful in some of my other usecases.